# An integral with Gamma functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

I wanted some insights about the integral in equation A.5 (page 19) in this paper, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.7182.pdf

- What is the derivation of this?
- Is there something more general from where this comes?
- If the $\vec{k}-\vec{q}$ of the denominator were replaced by $\vec{k}+\vec{q}$ would the only change be an overall factor of $(-1)^d$?
- One sees the Laurent series kind expansion of the Gamma function as stated in equation 3.8 (page 14). How can one use that to find the possibly similar pole structure in the RHS of the the integral in A.5?

Answer (score 7):

To clarify, for those who have not looked at the reference, the integral identity in question is
$$
  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{d^dq}{(q^2)^{\nu_1} ((k-q)^2)^{\nu_2}}
  = \frac{\Gamma(d/2-\nu_1)\Gamma(d/2-\nu_2)\Gamma(\nu_1+\nu_2-d/2)}
    {\Gamma(\nu_1)\Gamma(\nu_2)\Gamma(d-\nu_1-\nu_2)}
    \pi^{d/2} (k^2)^{d/2-\nu_1-\nu_2} ,
$$
where $q^2$ is standard Euclidean norm squared. I think this is not the standard way of deriving the answer, but the quickest way I see to get it is notice that this integral is a convolution, $$(2\pi)^d \frac{1}{(k^2)^{\nu_1}}*\frac{1}{(k^2)^{\nu_2}},$$ of two distributions and to use Fourier transforms to simplify it.

Basically, you need to take the Fourier transforms of $1/(q^2)^{\nu_1}$ and $1/(q^2)^{\nu_2}$ (that would be from momentum space to position space, in physics terminology), multiply them, and Fourier transform back. Luckily, the Fourier transforms of such distributions are well known. An explicit formula is given, for instance in formula 2.5 of the Fourier Transform Table Appendix of Gelfand & Shilov's [*Generalized Functions. Volume 1*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122795016):

\begin{align}
  \mathcal{F}[|x|^\lambda]
    &= \frac{\Gamma(\lambda/2+d/2)}{\Gamma(-\lambda/2)} 2^{\lambda+d} \pi^{d/2}
      |q|^{-\lambda-d} , \\
  \mathcal{F}^{-1}[|q|^\nu]
    &= \frac{\Gamma(\nu/2+d/2)}{\Gamma(-\nu/2)} 2^\nu \pi^{-d/2}
      |x|^{-\nu-d} ,
\end{align}
where $|q| = \sqrt{q^2}$, and with the conventions $\mathcal{F}[\delta(x)] = 1$, $\mathcal{F}[1] = (2\pi)^d\delta(q)$. If $q^2$ is computed using the Lorentzian inner product instead of the Euclidean one, similar formulas can be found, but they are more subtle: see formulas 2.13--16 of the same table in Gelfand & Shilov.

Putting this together with the convolution formula, and the fact that the product of two powers of $|x|$ is a power of $|x|$, the above integral is then
$$
  (2\pi)^d \frac{1}{(k^2)^{\nu_1}} * \frac{1}{(k^2)^{\nu_2}}
  = \frac{\Gamma(d/2-\nu_1)\Gamma(d/2-\nu_2)\Gamma(\nu_1+\nu_2-d/2)}
      {\Gamma(\nu_1)\Gamma(\nu_2)\Gamma(d-\nu_1-\nu_2)}
    \pi^{d/2} \frac{1}{(k^2)^{\nu_1+\nu_2 - d/2}} ,
$$
which is the desired form. The arithmetic can easily be checked by hand or with a computer algebra system (as I did it).

As for your last question, which asks for the pole structure of the above expression as a function of $d$, you need only know that $\Gamma(\nu)$ is never zero for real $\nu$ and that it has simple poles at $\nu=0$ and all negative integers, while the functional identity $\Gamma(\nu)\Gamma(1-\nu) = \pi/\sin(\pi \nu)$ tells you what the residues are.

Comment: "$d^d q$"?  Ouch!

Comment: Alas, not my notation.

Comment: Hmm, any comments to go along with the downvote?

Comment: @Igor Khavkine Thanks for the reply. The issue about the poles that I am confused about is this - for generic values of $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ all the $4$ Gamma functions in the value of the integral which have a $d$ in the argument are  going to get poles. So individually each of the $4$ Gamma functions has a pole. Now how does one multiply and divide such things? 

Comment: @Igor I don't have this book you refer to with me right now. Can you kindly write down the Fourier transform and the convolution steps? At least the steps and the results. (..I didn't get why you needed to Fourier transform to do the convolution..) 

Comment: @Igor Khavkine I guess you are using the convolution theorem somewhere (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvolutionTheorem.html). Seems you are doing the "inverse" of it - as in you are calculating the given convolution by taking the inverse Fourier transform of the product of the Fourier transforms of each. right? But I don't understand the technique of finding the poles when all the 4 functions few in denominator and few in the numerator) all can have poles! 

Comment: @curious,Anirbit: It's very simple to work through the details yourself, which is what I recommend. The steps are straightforward as long as you know some basic properties of Fourier transforms and convolutions. These you can look up on Wikipedia or in an elementary textbook. Same advice for figuring out the poles. The poles of a product are easy to get once you know the poles of the factors: just take products of the Laurent expansions. Even if you don't have access to Gelfand & Shilov, you can take my Fourier transform formulas for granted and check the rest of the arithmetic.

Comment: @Igor My question is this - the 3 $\Gamma$ functions in the numerator and one in the denominator are potentially going to have poles. Now is it legitimate to just ordinarily multiply the 3 Laurent series in the numerator and divide by the one in the denominator and then look for the pole of the result? Is such multiplication and division with Laurent series legal? Aren't there anything subtle? 

Comment: Yes, it's legitimate; no subtleties beyond consistently carrying out multiplication of series to a given order. Moreover, the $\Gamma$ function never vanishes on the real line, so the denominator does not contribute any poles.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Thanks! And I wanted to clarify if anything here changes if in the denominator instead of $k-q$ it were $k+q$? Also is this applicable for any value of $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$? 

Comment: @Anirbit: $(k+q)^2=[(-k)-q]^2$. The $\nu$s could be any complex number, excluding the poles of the final answer.

Comment: @Igor Khavkine My point about $k+q$ is this - if you see the linked reference then the answer is framed as "~k^$d - 2(\nu_1 + \nu_2)}$" In this form $k$ and $-k$ would give different answers. But you frame the answer as "$~(k^2)^(d/2 - (\nu_1+\nu_2))$" in which $k$ and $-k$ would give the same answers. 

Comment: @Anirbit: If that is what you are worried about, you should perhaps try an example, say, compute $k^3$ and $(k^2)^{1.5}$ for $k=(1,2,3)$. Think carefully about what the notation means.

Comment: @Igor Khavkine Ah..sorry..I guess the point is that the paper uses the notation of $k = \vert \vec{k} \vert$ and hence the flip of the sign doesn't matter and you get that effect by writing it as $\vec{k}.\vec{k}$. And I guess by thinking of $(\vec{k}+\vec{q})^2$ as $((-\vec{k}) - \vec{q})^2$ you are getting across the $(-1)^d$ issue that the OP had already mentioned. (...this is quite a queer integral I would say - very hard to find anywhere and softwares like Mathematica won't know either..) 

Comment: @Igor Khavkine You say that any $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ is allowed but isn't something uncomfortable happening when either or both are equal to $0$? 

Comment: @Anirbit, probably the best thing for you to do is get a copy of Gelfand and Shilov and read carefully through their treatment of these distributions.

Comment: @Igor Khavkine Hmm..I did find a copy in my library..hope to read up the details! Thanks for the help! 